# organize the map theme and style configuration file

Tags: cartography, style

I am working on an android application which render some features directly, but these different features should be rendered differently at different zoom level or only be visible from a certain zoom level.

So I think I need a config file to keep this information.

During the render I will read the file, and get the matched style for a given feature, and the render it.

Since all of these are done at the client side, so I think the file size should be as less a possible(consume less memory), and the speed of querying for a matched style should be as quick as possible.

I have no experience about organize this kind of file, so I wonder if someone can give me some suggestion?

BTW,all the data no matter points or lines have an property named "uid" to identify them from others.

Comment: Without providing a lot more specifics, you're unlikely to get much more than the kind of very general advice i've given below.

Comment: Was my answer acceptable? Do you mind letting us know by “accepting” it (i.e., click the ✔ check) and “upvoting” (click the Λ arrow)? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to organizing data or code, the more detail in which you can describe your problem the better. Think about, and start documenting, all the types, geometries, features, styles, scales, usage scenarios, and any other relevant factors involved. Rearrange your notes into tables. Sooner or later some logical patterns will emerge...

That's the GIS side of things. For the purely Android and config file side of the problem, you should probably be asking on Stack Overflow or other site.